# Issue to Forward Variable to Next Page ajax

Tags: php, ajax, ajaxform

I have page review.php which show the content by Get ID & reviews by users via Get ID.

On this review.php I have made a variable called $companyid ,

content is showing following to ID, but I have no idea how I forward my $companyid to page submit_rating.php via Ajax.

PHP code only the part where I made $companyid

```
          $_SESSION["company_id"] = $row["id"];
                    $companyid =  $row["id"];
```

This is HTML used for showing reviews and sending the reviews.

```
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="mt-5 mb-5">Review & Rating System in PHP & Mysql using Ajax</h1>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Sample Product</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                        <h1 class="text-warning mt-4 mb-4">
                            <b><span id="average_rating">0.0</span> / 5</b>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star star-light mr-1 main_star"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h3><span id="total_review">0</span> Review</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <p>
                            <div class="progress-label-left"><b>5</b> <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></div>

                            <div class="progress-label-right">(<span id="total_five_star_review">0</span>)</div>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="five_star_progress"></div>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <div class="progress-label-left"><b>4</b> <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></div>
                            
                            <div class="progress-label-right">(<span id="total_four_star_review">0</span>)</div>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="four_star_progress"></div>
                            </div>               
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <div class="progress-label-left"><b>3</b> <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></div>
                            
                            <div class="progress-label-right">(<span id="total_three_star_review">0</span>)</div>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="three_star_progress"></div>
                            </div>               
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <div class="progress-label-left"><b>2</b> <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></div>
                            
                            <div class="progress-label-right">(<span id="total_two_star_review">0</span>)</div>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="two_star_progress"></div>
                            </div>               
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <div class="progress-label-left"><b>1</b> <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></div>
                            
                            <div class="progress-label-right">(<span id="total_one_star_review">0</span>)</div>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="one_star_progress"></div>
                            </div>               
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                        <h3 class="mt-4 mb-3">Write Review Here</h3>
                        <button type="button" name="add_review" id="add_review" class="btn btn-primary">Review</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5" id="review_content"></div>
    </div>
```

Ajax submit_rating.php code
Please note that I made Temprory **$companyid= "118";** on this page, which I want this to get from review.php page dynamically. and than I'll remove it from this page.

````
//submit_rating.php
$companyid = "118";

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;***=****", "****", "");

if(isset($_POST["rating_data"]))
{

    $data = array(
        ':user_name'        =>  $_POST["user_name"],
        ':user_rating'      =>  $_POST["rating_data"],
        ':user_review'      =>  $_POST["user_review"],
        ':datetime'         =>  time(),
        'company_id'        =>  $companyid
    );
    
    $query = "
    INSERT INTO client_reviews 
    (user_name, user_rating, user_review, datetime, company_id) 
    VALUES (:user_name, :user_rating, :user_review, :datetime, :company_id)
    ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute($data);

    echo "Your Review & Rating Successfully Submitted";

}

if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    $average_rating = 0;
    $total_review = 0;
    $five_star_review = 0;
    $four_star_review = 0;
    $three_star_review = 0;
    $two_star_review = 0;
    $one_star_review = 0;
    $total_user_rating = 0;
    $review_content = array();

    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM client_reviews WHERE company_id = '$companyid'
    ORDER BY review_id DESC
    ";

    $result = $connect->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $review_content[] = array(
            'user_name'     =>  $row["user_name"],
            'user_review'   =>  $row["user_review"],
            'rating'        =>  $row["user_rating"],
            'datetime'      =>  date('l jS, F Y h:i:s A', $row["datetime"])
        );

        if($row["user_rating"] == '5')
        {
            $five_star_review++;
        }

        if($row["user_rating"] == '4')
        {
            $four_star_review++;
        }

        if($row["user_rating"] == '3')
        {
            $three_star_review++;
        }

        if($row["user_rating"] == '2')
        {
            $two_star_review++;
        }

        if($row["user_rating"] == '1')
        {
            $one_star_review++;
        }

        $total_review++;

        $total_user_rating = $total_user_rating + $row["user_rating"];

    }

    $average_rating = $total_user_rating / $total_review;

    $output = array(
        'average_rating'    =>  number_format($average_rating, 1),
        'total_review'      =>  $total_review,
        'five_star_review'  =>  $five_star_review,
        'four_star_review'  =>  $four_star_review,
        'three_star_review' =>  $three_star_review,
        'two_star_review'   =>  $two_star_review,
        'one_star_review'   =>  $one_star_review,
        'review_data'       =>  $review_content
    );

    echo json_encode($output);

}

?> ```
````

Comment: Well send it the same way you are sending the request of those parameters, `user_name`, `rating_data` and `user_review` ...?

Comment: That are being sent from the form, but the ID is not in form.

Comment: Well then why don't you put it in there.